# Clicking on a bitmap in Android Canvas

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I'm having a little bit of difficulty setting the (x,y) coordinate bounds to detect when a particular bitmap is being clicked on or not.

For example if the bitmap's position is (100,300),say. i.e. top left corner is at this point, then if the user touches the screen at point (X,Y), then the simple conditional:

```
if((Math.abs(X-midX)<bitmap.getWidth()/2)&&
           Math.abs(Y-midY)<bitmap.getHeight()<bitmap.getHeight()/2){

                  //the bitmap has been clicked on
}
```

Where midX is defined as (100+(100+bitmap.getWidth()))/2 i.e. the mid x point and similar definition for midY.

Is this a correct way to do this? Because some of my bitmaps are not behaving as I would expect when I try to touch/click them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I enjoy doing this kind of maths, this time I would recommend going 'the easy way'. Set up a Rect/RectF with your image bounds and use [rectF.contains(float x, float y)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/RectF.html#contains%28float,%20float%29) or [rect.contains(int x, int y)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html#contains%28int,%20int%29) instead. That is, if onClick is not an option here, of course.

Answer (score 0):

If you bitmap is in a `ImageView` you should be able to handle the `OnClickListener` for the view to know when the bitmap was selected.

Comment: It's not in an imageview. It's drawn on a canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to place the Bitmap in a Drawable and use it to test the bounds:

```
public boolean onSingleTap(MotionEvent event)
{
   int x = (int) event.getX();
   int y = (int) event.getY();

   if (drawable.getBounds().contains(x, y))
   {
      // You’ve tapped the Bitmap...
   }
}
```

Comment: instead of onSingleTap(MotionEvent event) we can use native method    onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event)